# Modeling WebSocket streams with RxJS

Tags: javascript, websocket, rxjs

What are the ways to model WebSocket streams with RxJS.

The obvious things I see are streams of sockets, that emit streams of messages.

If I create a stream oft sockets, how can I create streams of their messages and still preserve who sent these messages?

The socket stream was my first step:

```
const socket$ = Observable.create(({complete, next}) => {

  const server = new WebSocketServer({server: someHttpServer})

  server.on('connection', next)

  return () => {
    server.close()
    complete()
  }

})
```

But the message stream is a bit harder, because I need the sockets I got the messages from.

This was my fist naive try on modeling:

```
const message$ = socket$.flatMap(socket => Observable.create(({complete, next}) => {

  socket.on('message', next)
  socket.on('close', complete)

  return () => socket.close()

})).share()
```

A observable that streams all socket messages from all sockets. But if I subscribe to it, I don't have the sockets anymore, which makes this unidirectional.

I want

```
socket$ -> message$ -> server-processing -> socket$
```

But there are multiple use-cases for the responses, broadcast, multicast and unicast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that `flatMap` takes a second function, that receives the the argument value of `flatMap` AND the (flattened) return value of `flatMap`. This function can return a new value, that is used for all later operators.

```
const socketMessage$ = socket$.flatMap(

  socket => Observable.create(({complete, next}) => {

    socket.on('message', next)
    socket.on('close', complete)

    return () => socket.disconnect()

  }),

  (socket, message) => ({socket, message})

).share()
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if that's what you are looking for (what do you mean by `still preserve who sent these messages`), but there is a library for wrapping websockets in observables. Have a look at the documentation here : https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS-DOM/blob/master/doc/operators/fromwebsocket.md

Comment: Thank you, but this seems to be for clients. I added more details to my question :)

Comment: This library is now obsolete. It's been folded directly into RxJS: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/tree/master/src/internal/observable/dom